# How do you calculate Input output voltages of a trans-resistance op amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foaxoN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(a)Find Vn, Vp, and Vo
Ideal op amp
Vn = Vp
I think this is a transresistance (or transimpendance op amp) op amp
So Vo= -R1 x I1= 10k x 0.3mA = -3V,
Vp = [R2/(R2 +R3)]Vo= 20k/(20k+30k)=-1.2V
→ Vn = -1.2V

(b) Putting a resistance in parallel with the 0.3mA source, find Vn, Vp, and Vo.
My answer to this is that we will get the same results as in a because the new resistance is connected between Vn and ground and since there’s no current flowing into Vn that infers that there is no current flowing into the new resistance and consequently there is no voltage across it. What do you think about these answers in a and b?

Comment: You calculate the voltage across R1 but refer to it as R2. In the text you refer to R4 but there is no R4 in the schematic. This is all **very confusing**. If you want someone to answer/comment on this, at least make things consistent !

Comment: You're correct. Sorry for the confusion. I just updated it.

Comment: You missed Vo, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Your first calculation is correct in the sense that 300uA x 10 kohm = 3 V but that voltage is **across** R1, you assume Vn = 0 V which it isn't.

So 3 V across R1, note the direction of the current flow, so Vn - Vo = 3 V

We still do not know Vn or Vo yet !

Indeed R2, R3 is a voltage divider, your formula is correct.

Since we assume the opamp to operate in feedback correctly, we can assume Vp = Vn

Conveniently, since Vp = Vn we know that the voltage across R3 is the same as the voltage across R1 so also 3 V.

Conveniently R3 is 30 kohm and R2 is 20 kohm. The current is the same (it cannot go into the opamp) so the voltage across R2 (20 kohm) is 2 Volt.

The other side of R2 is grounded to Vp is 2 V, now you solve the rest !

For (b) you again assume Vn = 0 and that is not true ! To solve (b) you will have to write down all the equations and solve them.

You could also replace I1 and the extra resistor by its Thevenin equivalent if that helps.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! You've pointed me in the right direction.